# NSFileManager UUID app directory

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I'm using NSFileManager and i'm trying to copy a file to path "/var/mobile/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C/Document" the file will copy fine.

but the path of "7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C" is randomly changed in every time i delete and install the app again. So, is there a way to get the correct path of my app or search for file name, If file exist then replace\delete..etc the file? thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't tell you i want to use this with jailbroken device.

Comment: check the edit in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the absolute path, use something like

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"] toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"] error:nil];
```

This demonstrates copying the file `test.txt` from the apps bundle to the documents directory.
Do something like this to create a file `test.txt`

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"] contents:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a-cstudios.com/text.json"]] attributes:nil];
```

EDIT

If your using this and want to use it on a jailbroken device, to put something in the sandbox is the same as I said before, so you still don't have to use the UUID. If you want to put something in a system directory, that is when you would use something like `/usr/include/`, or wherever you want to. To put something in another apps sandbox, you *would* have to use the complete path, and you would have to know the UUID, as thats not part of your sandbox. So, unless you're copying a file to an app that *you* made, you have to use the complete path.

Comment: thanks to let me know that is calling a "absolute path". so how will this work [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C/Document" what about the absolute path?

Comment: The `@"/var/mobile/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌​/Document"` is unnecessary, as using `[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.txt"` returns that, except if the `7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌` changes you don't have to change the code, as it returns the documents directory of your sandbox.

Comment: i have check your code it's work but the file is write on "/mobile/Documents"

my app: "Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌​/Documents"

Comment: That's strange, because I just tested it and it wrote to the apps documents folder. Are you using the `documentsDirectory` string?

Comment: Yes, i use this as you give it to me: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"] toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"] error:nil]; but this wrote on "mobile/Documents" there something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any tweaks from Cydia that might cause that, and does your app have some kind of elevated permissions?

Comment: Let us assume my app path "/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌​/Document/Data.txt"

and copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt"] toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.txt"] error:nil]; will this work without "7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌"?

Comment: Oops, I'm on wrong way. Your method is working but that can be used for own app documents folder. this is good enough clear see my edit post.

EDIT:
Let us assume my app path root "Applications/MyApp.app/Data.txt" copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt"] toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.txt"] error:nil];

another app path will be: Home "/Applications/7AC2295E-2775-41EA-B017-AB4048A09F0C‌​/Document/"

Sorry for misunderstand me ^^

Comment: If you want to place a file in another apps directory, you have to use the whole path, e.g. `/var/mobile/Applications/number-number-number/App.app/`. The method I posted only works for files in your own app. Then, you have to change the code every time the app installs or uninstalls, or find a way to determine that number and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get access to the `Documents` directory in your app's sandbox is:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
```

Then you create your path:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.ext"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to write a file to its Documents directory.
use something like :

```
NSString  *filePath = NSHomeDirectory();
```

then append your actual file name to filePath.
then use filePath in your FileManager calls.

Comment: iOS provides a more direct approach for getting a reference to the `Documents` directory. See the other answers for the proper way. Using `NSHomeDirectory()` and hardcoding the name of the directory works but it's safer to use the direct approach.